# How to work with an existing SQL Server database

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I am starting my practices as a programmer, but I have a problem and that is that in the company where I am they gave me a test database that has 60 thousand data, I read the documentation where it says how to obtain the tables, I can do it, but at the moment of obtaining them these tables come with integer data in their foreign keys, is there any way to user the tables with the Django ORM, this my models:

```
from django.db import models


class TipoNovedad(models.Model):
    id_tnov = models.AutoField(db_column='Id_TNov', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    nom_nov = models.CharField(db_column='Nom_Nov', max_length=100)  # Field name made lowercase.
    desc_nov = models.CharField(db_column='Desc_Nov', max_length=250)  # Field name made lowercase.
    manejo_tiempo = models.CharField(db_column='Manejo_Tiempo', max_length=20)  # Field name made lowercase.
    dias = models.CharField(db_column='Dias', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    estado = models.BooleanField(db_column='Estado')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Tipo_Novedad'


class Novedades(models.Model):
    id_nov = models.AutoField(db_column='Id_Nov', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    # is in the foreign key of the novelty model
    id_tnov = models.IntegerField(db_column='Id_TNov')  # Field name made lowercase.
    n_identificacion = models.CharField(db_column='N_Identificacion', max_length=20)  # Field name made lowercase.
    fec_registro = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Fec_Registro')  # Field name made lowercase.
    fec_inicio = models.DateField(db_column='Fec_Inicio', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    fec_fin = models.DateField(db_column='Fec_Fin', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    fec_nov = models.DateField(db_column='Fec_Nov', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    hora_inicio = models.CharField(db_column='Hora_Inicio', max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    hora_fin = models.CharField(db_column='Hora_Fin', max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    report_tm = models.BooleanField(db_column='Report_TM')  # Field name made lowercase.
    id_usuario_creacion = models.IntegerField(db_column='Id_Usuario_Creacion')  # Field name made lowercase.
    id_usuario_ultimaactualizacion = models.IntegerField(db_column='Id_Usuario_UltimaActualizacion')  # Field name made lowercase.
    id_sedenov = models.IntegerField(db_column='Id_SedeNov', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    id_estadonov = models.IntegerField(db_column='Id_EstadoNov')  # Field name made lowercase.
    observacion = models.TextField(db_column='Observacion', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Novedades'
```

Comment: This link might be helpful https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: What I would like to know is that if I modify the field that has the IntegerField by a Foreign Key, would it be bad practice?

Comment: If it works, why not?

Comment: yes it worked thanks